# Errors Compiling NodeJS project in VS2015

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, mean-stack

I've inherited a MEANJS project that I've successfully managed to open in Visual Studio 2015 via the "Build me a project from existing Node code" route.

Unfortunately, I currently get > 2000 compilation errors!

In the 'node_modules (node)' directory it is complaining of Duplicate identifiers (TS2300). These point toward 2 identical compiler.ts files located under the following directories.

\node_modules\bower\node_modules\insight\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\rx\src\core\expressions\
\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\rx\src\core\expressions\

Is there an NPM 'tidy up everything' option that I could you please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to exclude the node_modules folder from the Project.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to clear npm cache by typing:

```
npm cache clear
```